# Internal connection fatal error c# wpf

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I've looked all over and found no solution.  I'm not to sure what is causing the problem, I'd greatly appreciate if anybody is able to help.  I'm still trying to learn the language.

```
     private void SignInButton_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        /// Check Username and password from text box
        string username = UserName.Text;
        string password = Password.Text;




        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=46.4.90.149\MyInstance,3306;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=XXXXXX;User ID=XXXXX;Password=XXXXXX");
        try
        {
            if (myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) 
                myConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
                myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Username, Password FROM PlayerInfo WHERE Username =@Username AND Password =@Password";
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password);
                int count = Convert.ToInt32(myCommand.ExecuteScalar());
                if(count==1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("HELLO YOU'RE LOGGED IN");
                    myConnection.Close();
                }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can't find account");
                myConnection.Close();
            }
        }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }





    }

}
```

}

I've tried multiple solutions, before it would throw `connection string is invalid`. I managed to fix that and now I get `internal error connection error 18.`

Comment: Do you know what line it occurs on, and can you post the stack trace?

Comment: It doesn't tell me what line it's on, where can i find the stack trace?

Comment: @SamIam i don't get any call stack errors actually?

Comment: The stack trace is part of your `Exception ex`.  If you do `MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());`, it should include it in the message box.  Or better yet, just put a breakpoint on that line, and get the stack trace from the debugger.